# How can I create a Drupal 8 view that includes all users with the same field value as the logged in user

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-views

Drupal 8. The fields are in a Profile Type, not User.
Scenario: User A color = blue, User B color = blue, User C color = red, User D color = red.
User A should see Users A and B in their view, and User D should see users C and D in their view.

Comment: Is profile type being created with a contrib module? If you don't find it when creating your view, I'm afraid you may need to look on how to create a custom module that will output a view for you, there you will need to take advantage of the Entity type for the profiles and get your custom view.

Comment: Thank you for asking. Contrib. module - Profile, D8. I have no problem finding the fields. I'll try to explain better (sry if I'm confusing...): I have a user (Susan) with a field that the references another user (e.g. Supervisor=Bob). I want a view that shows Susan (the logged in user) everyone who has the same field value she does (Supervisor=Bob). What Susan would then have is a view of all the people who report to her Supervisor, i.e., her co-workers... Once this is figured out, the field could be anything; everyone in Susan's Department, Location, etc.